# Are form elements outside of a FORM tag semantic html5?

Tags: forms, html

If I have a SELECT tag that will filter a table based on a user choice, does the SELECT tag need to be in a FORM tag (to be valid HTML5), if the resulting functionality will not work if JS disabled (i.e. we'll show the entire table or a 'more' link instead of doing a server-side filter on select of the form action/submit option (We may write the select in JS so it disappears from the markup if JS disabled.

Or do all form elements need to be in a form tag regardless of usage (and therefore a null 'action' attribute value).

I know HTML5 allows almost anything, I just couldn't find a definitive answer on W3, so thought I'd get your thoughts. Hope that makes sense.
Cheers.

Comment: How does semantics figure into this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics You meant "valid" or "well-formed" [html5], perhaps?

Answer (score 85):

All the form controls can be used anywhere where [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected, which means they can appear just about anywhere in the body of the document.  If you don't need to have them submitted back to a server then there's no need for them to be associated with a form, however I've noticed that in some browsers you can't take advantage of the [form validation features](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#client-side-form-validation) unless the elements can potentially be submitted.

One feature new to HTML5 is that form controls no longer need to be the direct child of a `form` element in order to be submitted with that form, the [`form` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms) allows you to specify the `id` of the form the element should be submitted with.

Comment: While robertc provided the authoritative links (and the best answer), here's the HTML5 spec in the "Edition for Web Authors" (a bit more readable): http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/content-models.html#phrasing-content-0

Answer (score 18):

It would appear that in HTML5 form elements can be outside of a `<form>` tag and still be valid;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Just making this valid</title>
</head>
<body>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

The above code validates successfully (minus the obvious character encoding errors).
I haven't read the entire HTML5 Spec, however the validator is usually correct on these sorts of matters.

Answer (score 4):

[The HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#form-owner) specifically allows `<input>`s (and other form-associated elements) not to have a `<form>`:

> A form-associated element can have a relationship with a `<form>` element, which is called the element’s **form owner**. If a form-associated element is not associated with a `<form>` element, its form owner is said to be null.

So feel free to use them wherever your heart desires!